# Converting preg_replace to preg_replace_callback on an array

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

I have a basic script in my chat engine that looks for urls and makes them clickable links for the users. I am using php 5.6 so I am getting the warning about `preg_replace` and using the callback function. While I can do it normally using the function, I am building this return using a fairly complex array and returning it to another complex array.

Here is the code I am currently using:

```
    return preg_replace(
        array(
            '/(?(?=<a[^>]*>.+<\/a>)(?:<a[^>]*>.+<\/a>)|([^="\']?)((?:https?|ftp|bf2|):\/\/[^<> \n\r]+))/iex',
            '/<a([^>]*)target="?[^"\']+"?/i',
            '/<a([^>]+)>/i',
            '/(^|\s)(www.[^<> \n\r]+)/iex', 
            '/(([_A-Za-z0-9-]+)(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@([A-Za-z0-9-]+)(\\.[A-Za-z0-9-]+)*)/iex'
        ),
        array(
            "stripslashes((strlen('\\2')>0?'\\1<a href=\"\\2\">\\2</a> <i class=\"fas fa-external-link-alt\"></i>\\3':'\\0'))",
            '<a\\1',
            '<a\\1 target="_blank">',
            "stripslashes((strlen('\\2')>0?'\\1<a href=\"http://\\2\">\\2</a> <i class=\"fas fa-external-link-alt\"></i>\\3':'\\0'))",
            "stripslashes((strlen('\\2')>0?'<a href=\"mailto:\\0\">\\0</a>':'\\0'))"
        ),
        $text
    );
```

My question is how can I rewrite my second argument to make it work using `preg_replace_callback` since I am using arrays. This **IS** similar to some other questions but they aren't returning their values or comparing them using an array and I've tried to write a return function similar to what other answer use and it just doesn't work. Any help with this would be appreciated!

Comment: See [`preg_replace_callback_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback-array.php).

Comment: Havent't tested it but there's a PHP < 7 in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, it's a lot different than the original preg_replace_callback so I have to figure out how to do it now haha